# Could not resolve placeholder value error for missing property in application.properties

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have following Java class:

```
@Component
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties("audit")
@Setter
@Getter
public class PlannerPropertyReader {

  @Value("#{'${audit.planner.collection-blacklist}'.split(',')}")
  private List<String> blacklistCollection;

}
```

Here `audit.planner` and `audit.planner.collection-blacklist` doesn't exist in Application.properties file. Therefore it throws

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'plannerPropertyReader': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'audit.planner.collection-blacklist' in value "#{'${audit.planner.collection-blacklist}'.split(',')}"
```

How we can set the default value if the property in @Value cannot be resolved?

Comment: You can add default values if the property is not available. please refer https://www.baeldung.com/spring-value-defaults

Comment: You should _really_ read the documentation on how `@ConfigurationProperties` works. You don't need `@Value`, and you can simply provide an actual array value in your YAML file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this:-

```
@Value("#{'${audit.planner.collection-blacklist:''}'.split(',')}")
```